# How to Configure Terraform for AWS China cn-north-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have terraform templates created for non-China AWS and now would like to adapt them for the China (cn-north-1) region. Simply changing the region to cn-north-1 isn't hitting the correct AWS APIs in the China region.

How do I configure terraform to use the China region? The APIs are also older in China compared to the non-China AWS APIs; how compatible is terraform with the AWS APIs in China?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

One thing that is easy to miss when porting configuration to `cn-north-1` is the correct [AWS partition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#genref-arns) in resource ARN, that is, all your ARN must begin with `arn:aws-cn:...` instead of `arn:aws:...`. You may find this [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/partition.html) helpful if you want to write manifests applicable to both CN and non-CN regions.

Another thing to pay attention to is specifying the correct service endpoints, e.g. in IAM trust policies. See the full list [here](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cnnorth_region).

This is probably it, as far as terraform is concerned, although one more subtlety that's useful to keep in mind is the [s3cmd configuration](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/wiki/Common-known-issues-and-their-solutions#7-problem-s3cmd-not-working-with-a-bucket-in-the-cn-north-1-region), should you require it.

Answer (score 0):

have you set `aws_region` in your TF file? https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/region.html